# c# check if a timespan range is between timespan range and how many hours

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan, date-range

Assuming I have 3 time ranges:

```
07:00 - 18:00  
18:00 - 23:00  
23:00 - 07:00
```

and the code:

```
public class TimeShift
{
   public TimeSpan Start { get; set; }
   public TimeSpan End { get; set; }
}

List<TimeShift> shifts = new List<TimeShift>();
```

How can I check if every item in the list is between the 3 ranges above and how many hours?

For example one `TimeShift` where:

```
Start: 07:00
End:   23:30
```

then that means 16.5 hours.

For the examples above:

```
Range 1: 11 hours  
Range 2: 5 hours  
Range 3: 0.5 hours
```

Comment: `.TotalHours` is available on `TimeSpan`. However, for shifts, I'd recommend using `DateTime` rather than `TimeSpan`. Or, a combination of `DateTime StartTime` and `TimeSpan Duration`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution including tests:

## Calc

```
public class TimeSpacCalculator
{
    public static TimeSpan GetTimeSpanIntersect(TimeShift input, TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end)
    {
        // Loopsback input from 23:59 - 00:00
        if (input.Start > input.End)
            return GetTimeSpanIntersect(new TimeShift(input.Start, TimeSpan.FromHours(24)), start, end) +
                   GetTimeSpanIntersect(new TimeShift(TimeSpan.FromHours(0), input.End), start, end);

        // Loopsback Shift from 23:59 - 00:00
        if (start > end)
            return GetTimeSpanIntersect(input, new TimeSpan(), end) +
                   GetTimeSpanIntersect(input, start, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
        if (input.End < start)
            return new TimeSpan();

        if (input.Start > end)
            return new TimeSpan();

        var actualStart = input.Start < start
            ? start
            : input.Start;

        var actualEnd = input.End > end
            ? end
            : input.End;

        return actualEnd - actualStart;
    }
}
```

## Classes

```
public class TimeRange : TimeShift
{
    public TimeRange(string name, TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end) : base(start, end)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TimeShift
{
    public TimeShift(TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public TimeSpan Start { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan End { get; set; }
}
```

## Tests

```
[TestFixture]
internal class TimShiftTests
{
    [Test]
    [TestCase(7, 23.5, 11, 5, 0.5)]
    [TestCase(22, 7.5, 0.5, 1, 8)]
    public void Test(double inputStartHours, double inputEndHours, double expectedRange1Hours, double expectedRange2Hours, double expectedRange3Hours )
    {
        var input = new TimeShift(TimeSpan.FromHours(inputStartHours), TimeSpan.FromHours(inputEndHours));

        var ranges = new List<TimeRange>
        {
            new TimeRange("Range1", TimeSpan.FromHours(7), TimeSpan.FromHours(18)),
            new TimeRange("Range2", TimeSpan.FromHours(18), TimeSpan.FromHours(23)),
            new TimeRange("Range3", TimeSpan.FromHours(23), TimeSpan.FromHours(7))
        };


        var result = new Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>();

        foreach (var range in ranges)
        {
            var time = TimeSpacCalculator.GetTimeSpanIntersect(input, range.Start, range.End);

            result.Add(range.Name, time);

            Console.WriteLine($"{range.Name}: " + time.TotalHours);
        }

        result["Range1"].Should().Be(TimeSpan.FromHours(expectedRange1Hours));
        result["Range2"].Should().Be(TimeSpan.FromHours(expectedRange2Hours));
        result["Range3"].Should().Be(TimeSpan.FromHours(expectedRange3Hours));
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Had to do something similar recently. Take a look at how I resolved it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40923461/5233410

Comment: If my shift starts from 22:00 and ends at 07:30 the next day, the result will be 0 for all. How can I resolve that?

Comment: @active92 Fixed the `GetTimeSpanIntersect` and updated Test to use TestCases and include your test case.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong types.  `Start` and `End` should be `DateTime`, not `TimeSpan`.  `End.Subtract(Start)` will provide a `TimeSpan` as its result.  The `TimeSpan` type has properties that will provide total number of hours, minutes, etc.

[TimeSpan Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a method to your class that represents the actual different between the start and end. For example call it timespan TimeDiff. you will need to include an if statement to confirm that TimeLater is less than TimeEnd and TimeEarlier is greater than TimeStart. Then the 'TimeDiff = TimeLater - TimeEarlier' .

TimeLater is the end of the range provided. And TimeEarlier is the beginning of a range provided.

If you want to calculate the timespan that goes past TimeEnd to TimeStart you will just perform need to perform a check that TimeEarlier is greater than TimeLater and have logic to calculate the difference. It would be along the lines of TimeDiff = (TimeEnd - TimeEarlier) + (TimeLater - TimeEnd)

To accomplish timespan subtraction use .Subtract() in all timespans

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution:

```
private double GetHours(TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end, TimeSpan startTarget, TimeSpan endTarget)
{
   double result = 0;
   if (startTarget >= start && endTarget <= end)
   {
      result = (endTarget - startTarget).TotalHours;
   }

   if ((startTarget >= start && startTarget < end) && endTarget > end)
   {
      result = (end - startTarget).TotalHours;
   }

   if (startTarget < start && (endTarget > start && endTarget <= end))
   {
      result = (endTarget - start).TotalHours;
   }

   if (startTarget < start && endTarget > end)
   {
      result = (end - start).TotalHours;
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Had to do something similar recently. Take a look at how I resolved it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40923461/5233410

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar requirement for a recent project. Here is my experience in solving the same issue.

Given the requirements, the following classes were derived.

```
public interface IRange<T> : IEquatable<T> where T : IComparable {
    T Maximum { get; }
    T Minimum { get; }
}

public sealed class Range<T> : IRange<T>
    where T : IComparable {
    public Range(T minimum, T maximum) {
        Minimum = minimum;
        Maximum = maximum;
    }

    public T Maximum { get; private set; }

    public T Minimum { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("{{{0} - {1}}}", Minimum, Maximum);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return ToString().GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) {
            return false;
        }
        return obj is Range<T> && Equals((Range<T>)obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(T other) {
        return object.Equals(this.ToString(), other.ToString());
    }

}
```

supported by the following extension methods

```
public static class Range {
    /// <summary>
    /// Create an <seealso cref="IRange&lt;T&gt;"/> using the provided minimum and maximum value
    /// </summary>
    public static IRange<T> Of<T>(T min, T max) where T : IComparable {
        return new Range<T>(min, max);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static bool Contains<T>(this IRange<T> range, T value) where T : IComparable {
        return range.Minimum.CompareTo(value) <= 0 && value.CompareTo(range.Maximum) <= 0;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsOverlapped<T>(this IRange<T> range, IRange<T> other, bool inclusive = false) where T : IComparable {
        return inclusive
            ? range.Minimum.CompareTo(other.Maximum) <= 0 && other.Minimum.CompareTo(range.Maximum) <= 0
            : range.Minimum.CompareTo(other.Maximum) < 0 && other.Minimum.CompareTo(range.Maximum) < 0;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static IRange<T> GetIntersection<T>(this IRange<T> range, IRange<T> other, bool inclusive = false) where T : IComparable {
        var start = new[] { range.Minimum, other.Minimum }.Max();
        var end = new[] { range.Maximum, other.Maximum }.Min();

        var valid = inclusive ? start.CompareTo(end) < 0 : start.CompareTo(end) <= 0;

        return valid ? new Range<T>(start, end) : null;
    }
}
```

Here is a test adapted to your particular requirements

```
[TestClass]
public class TimeShiftTests : MiscUnitTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TimeShiftDurationTest() {
        var shifts = new List<string>(){
            "07:00 - 18:00",
            "18:00 - 23:00",
            "23:00 - 07:00"
        }.Select(s => ParseShift(s));

        var timeShift = "07:00 - 23:30";
        var totalExpectedHours = 16.5;
        var input = ParseShift(timeShift);

        var intersections = shifts
            .Select(shift => shift.GetIntersection(input))
            .ToArray();

        intersections.Length.Should().Be(3);

        var actualHours = intersections.Select(range => (range.Maximum - range.Minimum).TotalHours).ToArray();

        var totalActualHours = actualHours.Sum();

        totalActualHours.Should().Be(totalExpectedHours);

        actualHours[0].Should().Be(11);
        actualHours[1].Should().Be(5);
        actualHours[2].Should().Be(0.5);

    }

    private IRange<DateTime> ParseShift(string period, string format = "HH:mm") {
        var tokens = period
            .Split(new[] { "to", "-" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(s => s.Trim().Replace(" ", string.Empty))
            .ToArray();

        if (tokens.Length != 2) throw new FormatException("time period not well formatted");

        var startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tokens[0], format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var stopDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tokens[1], format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        var beginTime = startDate.TimeOfDay;
        var endTime = stopDate.TimeOfDay;

        if (endTime < beginTime) {
            stopDate = stopDate.AddDays(1);
        }

        return Range.Of(startDate, stopDate);
    }
}
```