# How to figure out wether a range of timespan is between which range of timespan

Tags: c#, linq, timespan

Let's say I have two timespan ranges

```
07.00.00 - 18.59.59
19.00.00 - 06.59.59
```

Now i have a timespan range, let's call it a duration.

```
public class Duration {
  public TimeSpan StartingTime{get; set;}
  public TimeSpan EndingTime{get; set;}
}
```

Which is initialized as

```
StartingTime 05.00.00
EndingTime 06.00.00
```

I would like to generate a method where i Pass in the list of timespan ranges, and a new Timespan, where it would return me a correct timespan range.

I have tried modifying [Check if a date range is within a date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786821/check-if-a-date-range-is-within-a-date-range) for TimeSpan, also, tried to convert my timespan ranges to datetime, but it resulted in fail (returning nothing).

Also I've tried going with

```
var fee = fees.Where(a=> parking.StartTime <= a.EndingTime && parking.EndTime >= a.StartingTime).First();
```

Where parking would be the duration class, and fees would be a list of timespan ranges.

Also I've looked at [c# check if a timespan range is between timespan range and how many hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922409/c-sharp-check-if-a-timespan-range-is-between-timespan-range-and-how-many-hours) but this did not result in working solution either.

I am quite frustrated already, and could not think out a solution.

EDIT: Taking example of @NetMage there was a case where 19.40 - 20.35 would result in fail, which I fixed adding another condition.

```
var fee = fees
                .First(r => (r.StartingTime <= r.EndingTime) ?
                        (r.StartingTime <= parking.StartTime && parking.StartTime <= r.EndingTime) :
                        (parking.StartTime <= r.EndingTime) ?
                        (r.StartingTime <= parking.StartTime + oneDay && parking.StartTime <= r.EndingTime)
                        : (r.StartingTime <= parking.StartTime + oneDay && parking.StartTime <= r.EndingTime + oneDay)
                        );
```

EDIT2//

Now I am still having problems with checking the overlap from endTime. Tried using the method that NetMage told, but so far nothing

EDIT3//

To check for the ending part it would be

```
fees.First(r => (r.StartingTime <= r.EndingTime) ?
                        (r.EndingTime >= end && end >= r.StartingTime) :
                        (end >= r.StartingTime) ?
                        (r.EndingTime >= end + oneDay && end >= r.StartingTime) :
                        (r.EndingTime >= end + oneDay && end >= r.StartingTime + oneDay)
                        );
```

And Finally to check wether it overlaps both ways:

```
fees.First(r => r.StartingTime >= start && r.EndingTime <= end);
```

Comment: Can you post your model for fees?

Comment: And does your parking variable implement the Duration model?

Comment: Also confused as to exactly what type of output you are looking for.  Is it any fee that is outside or the specified range or is it for any fee that is within the specified range?

Comment: Um, why did you implement duration during TimeSpans and not DateTimes? Better yet, why have a duration class at all, and not just use one TimeSpan?

Comment: Can you give an example of inputs and expected outputs please?

Comment: @stybl. A dateTime has to be different for every day. He may not care about the day. Also a TimeSpan doesn't specify when the timespan starts, only its length.

Comment: Exactly. I don't care about the date, just the timeranges.

my model for fees is List of durations. The parking is actually the duration, with some extra information that i don't care about in that scope.

@DavidLee Within the specified range

is it possible to have timespan as a range?

Comment: Egert uses the TimeSpan in the same meaning as property TimeSpan.TimeOfDay does, namely: the fraction of the day that has elapsed since midnight

Comment: Can you edit your question to define "correct timespan range" in detail? Also, what is a "list of timespan ranges" - is it `List<Duration>` ?

Comment: I think you should define three ranges, all together covering one day: 00:00 - 6:59:56, 07:00:00-18.59.59, 19.00.00 - 23:59:59, because you can't easily work with timespan ranges if they cross midnight.

Comment: It is not very obvious what the hangup could be, you did not show any attempt at making it work.  The classic mistake is not accounting for midnight being in the interval.  So, say, a start time of 8 o'clock in the evening and an end time of 4 o'clock in the morning.  You have to add 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your list of time ranges is a `List<Duration>`, you can query like so:

```
var OneDay = new TimeSpan(24,0,0);

var startAns = ranges.First(r => {
    var rEndingTime = (r.StartingTime > r.EndingTime) ? r.EndingTime + OneDay : r.EndingTime;
    return (r.StartingTime <= parking.StartingTime && parking.StartingTime <= rEndingTime) ||
           (r.StartingTime <= parking.StartingTime + OneDay && parking.StartingTime + OneDay <= rEndingTime);
});

var endAns = ranges.First(r => {
    var rEndingTime = (r.StartingTime > r.EndingTime) ? r.EndingTime + OneDay : r.EndingTime;
    return (r.StartingTime <= parking.EndingTime && parking.EndingTime <= rEndingTime) ||
           (r.StartingTime <= parking.EndingTime + OneDay && parking.EndingTime + OneDay <= rEndingTime);
});
```

I replaced the original (conceptually) `Let` based answer below with the above ones, also using the nice `First` variant the OP used.

```
var ans = ranges.Select(r => new { r, r.StartingTime, EndingTime = (r.StartingTime > r.EndingTime ? r.EndingTime + OneDay : r.EndingTime)})
                .Where(r => (r.StartingTime <= parking.StartingTime && parking.StartingTime <= r.EndingTime) ||
                            (r.StartingTime <= parking.StartingTime+OneDay && parking.StartingTime+OneDay <= r.EndingTime))
                .Select(r => r.r).First();
```

Comment: Hello @NetMage This is quite good solution, but this fails in case when the time is for example 19:40 – 20:35 . This is because condition 

parking.StartTime <= r.EndingTime 

is false (StartTime is 19:40 whereas EndingTime is 06.59.59.

Perhaps we should create another condition in there?

Comment: If Possible, could you help me think out the similar thing for end time overlap as well.

Comment: You are correct, the optimize version doesn't work in all cases. I added the expression for `parking.EndingTime`.

Answer (score 0):

*Updated to resolve issue with period rollover to next day*

Using `TimeSpan` is quite neat for this purpose, but in the case where a period rolls into the next day, this would make the query quite complex and unwieldy.

This can be easily resolved, by splitting the Period that covers two days into two Periods as follows:

```
00.00.00 - 06.59.59 //off peak 1
07.00.00 - 18.59.59 //peak
19.00.00 - 23.59.59 //off peak 2
```

In your example you have two possible cases that you need to handle:

1. Parking duration is entirely in one Fee period - which your query handles.
2. Parking duration overlaps two (or more periods) - your query will not match any results for this and will crash because you're using `.First()`

To get more accurate answers you'll need to specify what your required behaviour should be. On the off chance that these might be suitable, here are two possibilities:

This query will return the Fee period that the Parking **starts** in:

`var fee = fees.Where(period => 
parking.StartTime >= period.StartingTime && parking.StartTime <= period.EndingTime).First();`

This query will return the Fee period that the Parking **ends** in:

`var fee = fees.Where(period => 
parking.EndTime >= period.StartingTime && parking.EndTime <= period.EndingTime).First();`

Comment: The starting part is exactly what I was looking for. Cheers.

EDIT// on second look. It still fails, because in that case it should fall into the range of 19.00.00 - 06.59.59.  But as startingTime 05.00.00 for example is not bigger than period startingtime (19.00.00) this still returns an error.

Comment: @EgertAia Your range confuses me.  You have it starting at 19 and ending at 7.  How can your starting period be greater than your ending period?  Is this because it goes into the next day?

Comment: @EgertAia I see - answer updated with my suggestion to resolve that. It could be done with a query, but I think this is a better solution.